# Syntax error on assigning value to var in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple function that should look at a value on my form, and if it's not null or empty to add some text and a carraige return to that var and save it for later, with the idea of putting several of these together later, skipping any with a null value.  I have 11 textboxes on this particular form, although I am only starting with building this out for two, I will add all 11 later.

My (first) issue is that it's giving me a syntax error on assigning the value to a var.  I won't be surprised if there's more ways to do this better.

```js
function CompileEm() {
  document.getElementById("txtFileNote").value = null
  var s1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value
  if (s1 !== null && s1 !== '') {
    document.getElementById("txtFileNote").value = "1st Entry:  " + s1 + '\n'
  }
  var s2 = document.getElementById("txt2").value
  var t2 = document.getElementById("txtFileNote").value
  if ((isNullOrEmpty(s3)))
    if (s2 !== null && s2 !== '') {
      document.getElementById("txtFileNote").value = t2 + '\n' + "2nd Entry:  " + s2 + '\n'
    }
}
```

I admit that javascript is not my forte.  HALP!

Comment: What is `isNullOrEmpty(s3)`? There is neither a `s3` nor `isNullOrEmpty` in your code

Comment: I don't believe this is a syntax error, I ran your code in my console and it ran fine, the only error was because my console has no html elements with those IDs, so it can't find `value` of undefined. Is that the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: This code really should be rethought because it is basically just a bunch of copy and paste. A simple loop could simplify the code.

Comment: `a syntax error on assigning the value to a var.`  Can you be more specific?  You are assigning multiple values to multiple vars.  What is the specific error?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially a giant copy/paste function.  There are better ways to do this, but they want it nested into an xhtml page they already use.

Comment: Also, It's giving me that syntax error every time I'm assigning a value to a variable inside this function.  If I comment out var s1 and start on var s2, that's where the error is.

'isNullOrEmpty(s3)' should be s2, I typo'd on the console.  'isNullOrEmpty' was my first iteration of attempting to sense if a value was null before I settled on the '(s2 !== null && s2 !== '')' method

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the comments make sense:

```
    function CompileEm()
    {
        document.getElementById("txtFileNote").value = ''; // use empty string to start with
        var total = 11; // you should really get this dynamically, like using document.querySelectorAll('XXX').length, where 'XXX' is the CSS query that targets all your boxes. probably something like 'input[type="text"]' but I don't know what your HTML looks like.
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            var text = document.getElementById("txt" + i).value; // this assumes you've ID'd all your textboxes like txt1, txt2, txt3, ... 
            if (text) // if not null or empty
            {
                // concatenate with +=
                document.getElementById("txtFileNote").value += "Entry #" + i + ": " + text + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't have a regular format for the textbox IDs, then you have to loop over the array result of `document.querySelectorAll('XXX')`:

```
    function CompileEm()
    {
        document.getElementById("txtFileNote").value = ''; // use empty string to start with
        var allTextBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'); // modify this selector to match your needs
        for (var i = 0; i < allTextBoxes.length; i++)
        {
            var textBox =  allTextBoxes[i];
            if (textBox.value) // if not null or empty
            {
                // concatenate with +=
                document.getElementById("txtFileNote").value += "Entry with ID " +  textBox.id + ": " + textBox.value + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really like this idea.  I have ID'd my textboxes in a way that this would work, but the  entries are string.  '1st Entry' and '2nd Entry' are just placeholders, the actual values have yet to be given to me, but they will be unique and not sequential numbers, so Iwon't be able to loop through them.